# Get value from Instance in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am making a search request on the List with the Provider pattern.

```
List<Device> _devices = [
    Device(one: 'Apple', two: 'iphone'),
    Device(one: 'Samsung', two: 'Galaxy')
];
```

And Query is like this

```
List<Device> queryQuery(String value) {
return _devices
    .where((device) => device.one.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()))
    .toList();
```

the result I expect to get is **iphone** when I passed the value **Apple**.

But the result on the screen that I got is **[instance of ‘Device’]**
when I code like this

```
child: Text('${deviceData.getDevice('Apple')}'
```

I do know I should be using some kind of key using **two**... but I have no idea :-(

Comment: override `toString()` method for `Device` object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You serialized the wrong object.

What you did end-up being similar to:

```dart
Text(Device(one: 'Apple', two: 'iphone').toString());
```

But you don't want to do `Device.toString()`. What you want instead is to pass `Device.two` to your `Text`.

As such your end result is:

```dart
Text('${chordData.chordExpand('Apple').two}')
```

Comment: Like you said, I want to pass `Device.two` value to `Text` on the screen.
But the query above returns `List<Device>` value and returns `The getter two isn't defined for the class 'List<Device>'.` error. The same errror comes when I changed the query type to `Text` ... `The getter two isn't defined for the class 'String`

Comment: Then do a `.map((device) => device.two)`

Comment: Hello, would you help me solve this issue? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60386200/object-query-and-remove-parentheses-in-dart-flutter

Answer (score 1):

By the look of [Instance of 'Device'], it seems the function is returning a list so it is a good idea to check if the list is empty or not. if it is not empty, one of the elements is still needed to be selected. I guess it should be Text('${chordData.chordExpand('Apple')[0].two}') in case the list is not empty.

To summarize, use something like this to handle the case when list is empty

```
// Inside your build method before returning the widget
var l = chordData.chordExpand('Apple'); // Returns a list of devices
String textToWrite; // Here we will store the text that needs to be written
if(l.isEmpty) textToWrite = 'No results'; // If the filter resulted in an empty list
else textToWrite = l[0].two; // l[0] is an instance of a device which has a property called two. You can select any instance from the list provided it exists

return <Your Widget>(
.....
Text(textToWrite),
.....
);
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked when I do `.map((device) => device.two)`. I will add a empty check function in case the list is empty.