# object query and remove parentheses in dart, flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, where-clause, flutter-provider

Hello? I'm building an app using the flutter provider pattern. And I created a process to query the values ​​inside the object. I also have data in my model dart file.

Check the code below.

```
List<Device> _devices = [
    Device(one: 'apple', two: 'iphone'),
    Device(one: 'samsung', two: 'galaxy')
];


String Query(String value) {
    return _media.where((medium) => medium.one == value)
                    .map((medium) => (medium.two)).toString();

Query("apple")
```

So, when I call that function, I expect `iphone` to be returned. But the results come in `(iphne)`. Actually I know why. After all, the data returned is a `List<Device>` type. But what I want is to remove the parentheses by returning only the first value in the queried list(meaning only queried list, not the full list). In other words, I want to receive `iphone`, not `(iphone)`. Currently, I am using `substring` removing the first and the final word, which seems to have some limitations. Is there any way to remove parentheses in that logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have parentheses because you're calling `.toString()` on a list:

```dart
return _media.where((medium) => medium.one == value)
  .map((medium) => (medium.two))
  .toString();
```

To return just `.two` or the first found object, you just have to do:

```dart
return _media.firstWhere(
  (medium) => medium.one == value, orElse: () => null)?.two;
```

That will return the value of `.two` of the first found object or `null` if nothing found.

Doc: [Iterable.firstWhere()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html)

Comment: Thanks. firstWhere seems to take only one argument. I tried remove the second params but I only get -- Bad state: No element -- error.

Comment: issue solved by changing... `return _media.firstWhere(
  (medium) => medium.one == value, orElse: () => null)?.two;`